# How to create a widgetized sidebar for a theme with no sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

Please could someone show me how to do this? My theme (Fable) does not have a built-in sidebar and I need one for my homepage.

Many thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Where di you look? Why did it not work?

Comment: If your theme does not offer a sidebar, you can either 1) stop using it and move to entirely different one with a sidebar and 2) stop using it and create a child theme with a sidebar. I don't see the third option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a child theme.
2. Create a file sidebar.php.
3. In your sidebar.php-file you have to use at least the following function: `dynamic_sidebar()`
4. Furthermore in your functions.php file of your child Theme you must use the following functions: `register_sidebar()`
5. Include the sidebar in your child theme (most probably in the overwritten index.php-file)
6. Style the sidebar to integrate it with your Theme properly.

For further documentation see the WordPress Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your functions.php file:

```
<?php
// Declare sidebar widget zone   
register_sidebars( 1,
array(
    'name' => 'My Widget Area',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
     )
   );
?>
```

Then put this in the place in your theme where you want the widget area to appear:

```
<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('My Widget Area')) : else : ?><?php endif; ?>
```